Are there functions $f,g$ for which $f \circ g$ is differentiable at $a$, $f'(g(a))$ exists and is nonzero, but $g$ is not differentiable at $a$?
As a common univariate calc exercise after learning the chain rule, a student will be asked to find functions, $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for which $g$ is not differentiable at some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, but $f$ is differentiable at $g(a)$ and $f \circ g$ is differentiable at $a$. A common example is $f = 0$ and $g(x) = |x|$. With that choice, $f = f \circ g = 0$ is everywhere differentiable, but $g$ is not differentiable at $0$.
If we impose the additional constraint $f'(g(a)) \neq 0$, is that sufficient to guarantee that $f \circ g$ is not differentiable at $a$?
I've tried proof by contradiction to determine whether the differentiability of $f \circ g$ at $a$ implies the differentiability of $g$ at $a$, but I can't find such a route.
My efforts to compose counterexamples ($f,g$ with $g$ not differentiable at $a$, $f'(g(a)) \neq 0$ exists, and $f \circ g$ differentiable at $a$) have similarly been fruitless so far.

If you're happy for $g$ to be discontinuous at $a$ this is fairly easy. Are you looking for an example where it is continuous?

Here's a proof under the additional assumption that there's some punctured neighborhood of $x=a$ on which $g(x)\ne g(a)$ (as well as continuity of $g(x)$ at $x=a$).
We tweak the proof of the chain rule, writing
$$
\frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x-a} = \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{x-a} \bigg/ \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x) - g(a)}.
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to a} \frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x-a} &= \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{x-a} \bigg/ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x) - g(a)} \\
&= (f\circ g)'(a) \bigg/ \lim_{y\to g(a)} \frac{f(y) - f(g(a))}{y - g(a)} = (f\circ g)'(a) \big/ f'(g(a))
\end{align*}
exists (since $f'(g(a))\ne0$), contrary to the assumption that $g'(a)$ does not exist.
Note that the additional assumption is used twice, first to ensure that $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(g(x)) - f(g(a))}{g(x) - g(a)}$ makes sense in the first place, and then to justify the change of variables into $\lim_{y\to g(a)} \frac{f(y) - f(g(a))}{y - g(a)}$ since this function is undefined at $y=g(a)$ itself.

You don't even need the condition that $g(x) \neq g(a)$ on the punctured neighborhood. Any sequence $x_n \rightarrow a$ close enough to $a$ can be divided into at most two subsequences, the first ${y_n}{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $g(y_n) \neq g(a)$ for all $n$, and the second ${z_n}{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $g(z_n) = g(a)$ for all $n$. For the $y_n$ you argue as in your answer, and for the $z_n$, if they exist, the difference quotient for $g$ is always zero and also $(f \circ g)'(a) = 0$ so that the limit of both sequences of difference quotients equals zero, in which case $g'(a) = 0$.
